# unable to build a custom module CentOS 7

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to build a kernel module in CentOS 7. When I run make, I get the following

```
$ make
make -C /usr/src/kernels/`uname -r` SUBDIRS= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64'
Makefile:641: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Based on my online reading it looks like I don't have the kernel sources.

I followed [these instructions](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source), but was still getting the same error.

I also found [these instructions](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BuildingKernelModules), however ran intro the problem right at the beginning.

Here is the statement at the beginning of the page:

> It is assumed that you already have the full kernel source tree
>   installed. If you followed **Section 2** of [I need the Kernel Source](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source), it
>   will be found in the directory 
>   `~/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.18/linux-2.6.18.uname -m/`

Here is what I get when I run `tree ~/rpmbuild`

```
/home/user/rpmbuild
|-- BUILD
|-- BUILDROOT
|-- RPMS
|-- SOURCES
|   |-- centos.cer
|   |-- centos-kpatch.x509
|   |-- centos-ldup.x509
|   |-- check-kabi
|   |-- cpupower.config
|   |-- cpupower.service
|   |-- debrand-rh-i686-cpu.patch
|   |-- debrand-rh_taint.patch
|   |-- debrand-single-cpu.patch
|   |-- extra_certificates
|   |-- kernel-3.10.0-ppc64.config
|   |-- kernel-3.10.0-ppc64-debug.config
|   |-- kernel-3.10.0-ppc64le.config
|   |-- kernel-3.10.0-ppc64le-debug.config
|   |-- kernel-3.10.0-s390x.config
|   |-- kernel-3.10.0-s390x-debug.config
|   |-- kernel-3.10.0-s390x-kdump.config
|   |-- kernel-3.10.0-x86_64.config
|   |-- kernel-3.10.0-x86_64-debug.config
|   |-- kernel-abi-whitelists-514.tar.bz2
|   |-- linux-3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.tar.xz
|   |-- linux-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.tar.xz
|   |-- linux-kernel-test.patch
|   |-- Makefile.common
|   |-- Module.kabi_dup_ppc64
|   |-- Module.kabi_dup_ppc64le
|   |-- Module.kabi_dup_s390x
|   |-- Module.kabi_dup_x86_64
|   |-- Module.kabi_ppc64
|   |-- Module.kabi_ppc64le
|   |-- Module.kabi_s390x
|   |-- Module.kabi_x86_64
|   |-- secureboot.cer
|   |-- sign-modules
|   `-- x509.genkey
|-- SPECS
|   `-- kernel.spec
`-- SRPMS
```

My `BUILD` directory is empty. What is it I need to do to be able to compile a kernel module in CentOS7?

Here is the code for kernel module

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int __init ofd_init(void) {
  printk(KERN_INFO, "OFD registered");
  return 0;
}

static int __exit ofd_exit(void) {
  printk(KERN_INFO, "OFD unregistered");
  return 0;
}

module_init(ofd_init);
module_exit(ofd_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Test");
```

And here is the makefile for it

```
# makefile - makefile for test

# If KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernek build system and need to use its language
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := ofd.o
# Otherwise we've been invoked from the command line.
# Invoke the kernel build system
else
    KERNEL_SOURCE := /usr/src/kernels/`uname -r`
    PWD := $(shel pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SOURCE) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SOURCE) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed the source tree extracting process.

From https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source：

> As an ordinary user, not root, install the source package by executing:

```
[user@host]$ rpm -i http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/updates/Source/SPackages/kernel-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.src.rpm 2>&1 | grep -v exist
```

This will unpack the kernel source tree to `~/rpmbuild/BUILD`.